# Get Informations from an span class (Website Development)

Tags: javascript, css, web

```
<span class="score" title="286 up, 34 down">252</span>
```

He displays only 252. How can i edit it that he show "286 up, 34 down" too?

It's not my website. It would be a mod. I think it's not possible to do this with the CSS Mod "Stylish" or are i'm wrong?

I think i have to write an Javascript Mod. Is that Possible?

Thanks for answers.

P.S. please don't give a CODE SOLUTION. I want to write it by myself. I want only to know in which programming language i have to write and it is possible.

Comment: This is not possible with CSS. With JavaScript maybe, but then again, how are you going to put that script in the other person's website?

Comment: Technically you can do it with CSS, but I won't say how because he doesn't want a code solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `::before` pseudo selector with CSS and for `content` use `attr()`. Btw, you should also use `data` for custom attributes like this:

```
<span class="score" data-title="286 up, 34 down">252</span>
```

You didn't want a code solution, but I don't think I'm spoiling much by showing you this CSS:

```
.score::before{
  content:attr(data-title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prefer use the prefix **data-** before custom HTML attributes to avoid future conlicts. On way to achieve what you want is exactly how *Ilpo Oksanen* has said:

```
.score:before {
  content: attr(title);
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/04ogmkwr/

Another way *(if you want to keep 252 and append title attribute value)* is to use javascript:

```
(function(){
    var element = document.getElementsByClassName('score')[0];
    var title = element.attributes.getNamedItem('title');
    element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML + ': ' + title.value;
})();
```

If you have several elements on screen, it's just to make a *for(...)*

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adhLtpwL/

Answer (score -1):

Check out generated content using a pseudo element such as .score:after

With a content rule you can use the value of the title attribute.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content

Check out line 16 of the example syntax.